# How can I store MQTT data into QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I am building a solution that uses Mosquitto for brokering IoT sensor data. The IoT sensors are publishing to MQTT topics and I would like to store the payload data in QuestDB for analysis, what are some options for using this as storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest and fastest ways of ingesting data from MQTT topics into QuestDB is to use Telegraf to stream records via InfluxDB line protocol. The configuration for Telegraf would look something like the following:

```yaml
# Configuration for Telegraf agent
[agent]
  ## Default data collection interval for all inputs
  interval = "5s"
  hostname = "qdb"

[[outputs.socket_writer]]
  # Write metrics to a local QuestDB instance over TCP
  address = "tcp://127.0.0.1:9009"

[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  ## The MQTT broker
  servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]

  ## Topics that will be subscribed to.
  topics = [
    "telegraf/host01/cpu",
    "telegraf/+/mem",
    "sensors/#",
  ]
```

For more information on the MQTT consumer for Telegraf, see the [plugin's README which has usage info](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/release-1.19/plugins/inputs/mqtt_consumer/README.md) (use with SSL etc.)

Additionally, I would point out that there are some tools such as [this example stack](https://questdb.io/tutorial/2020/08/25/questitto/) which has the MQTT broker, Telegraf and QuestDB defined as networked services.